# Problem $2.17$, Rudin's RCA (Dictionary Order Topology)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, riesz-representation-theorem

> **Problem $2.17$:** Define the distance between the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ in the plane to be $$|y_1-y_2| \quad \text{if }x_1 = x_2, \quad\quad 1+|y_1 - y_2|\quad \text{if } x_1\ne x_2$$
> Show that this is indeed a metric, and that the resulting metric space $X$ is locally compact.
>
> If $f\in C_c(X)$, let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be those values of $x$ for which $f(x,y)\ne 0$ for at least one $y$ (there are only finitely many such $x$!), and define $$\Lambda f = \sum_{j=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x_j,y)\ dy$$
> Let $\mu$ be the measure associated with this $\Lambda$ by Theorem $2.14$. If $E$ is the $x$-axis, show that $\mu(E) = \infty$ although $\mu(K) = 0$ for every compact $K\subset E$.

Theorem $2.14$ above refers to the Riesz representation theorem, which relates $\mu$ with the linear functional $\Lambda$. I found a solution to the above problem [here](https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1415/math5011/MATH5011_Solution_4.2014.pdf), which I need some help with understanding. I've reproduced it to the extent necessary below.

---

Hereafter, the *distance* defined above (between points in $\mathbb R^2$) is represented by $d$, and it is indeed a metric. It was also proved that $(X,\tau)$ is a LCHS (locally compact Hausdorff space), by identifying it as $(X,\tau) = (\mathbb R, \tau_1) \times (\mathbb R,\tau_2)$ where $\tau_1$ is the discrete topology on $\mathbb R$, and $\tau_2$ is the usual one. If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the metrics corresponding to these topologies, it is easy to see that the product metric $d = d_1 + d_2$. *Now, the real problem begins.*

1. If $f\in C_c(X)$, why is it that there are only finitely many $x$ for which $f(x,y)\ne 0$ for at least one $y$? The link I've attached says:

> If $K$ is compact in $X$, the first projection $\text{pr}_1(K)$ is compact in $(\mathbb R, τ_1)$. Hence
> it is a finite set. Therefore $K$ is a finite union $$\{x_1\} × K_1 ∪ · · · ∪ \{x_n\} × K_n$$ where each $K_i$, $i = 1, 2, . . . , n$, is a compact set in $(\mathbb R, τ_2)$.

Here's my reasoning (please confirm if it is correct): Take $K = \text{supp}(f) = \overline{\{(x,y): f(x,y)\ne 0\}}$. Since $f\in C_c(X)$, $K$ is compact, and its projection $\text{pr}_1(K)$ is also compact. In the discrete topology, sets are compact iff they are finite, so $\text{pr}_1(K)$ is finite. Since projection maps preserve inclusion, we have $\text{pr}_1(\{(x,y): f(x,y)\ne 0\}) \subset \text{pr}_1(K)$ is finite. Now, $\text{pr}_1(\{(x,y): f(x,y)\ne 0\}) = \{x: \exists y, f(x,y)\ne 0\}$ which is finite (as the claim requires).

2. In the very next paragraph, they mention that the support of $f\in C_c(X)$ is contained in $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}\times\mathbb R$. How do we use this to deduce that $\Lambda$ is a positive linear functional on $C_c(X)$?
3. How do we get $\mu(\{x\} \times K) = m(K)$?
4. 

> Let $V$ be an open set containing $\mathbb R × \{0\}$. Then for $x ∈ \mathbb R$, $(x, 0) ∈ V$ , so
> that there exists an $ε_x > 0$ with $\{x\} × [−ε_x, ε_x] ⊂ V$. This implies that there must be an $n$ with uncountably many $ε_x \ge 1/n$. (Otherwise, $ε_x \ge 1/n$ for at most countably many $x$, contradicting the fact that $\mathbb R$ is uncountable.) Let $K_x = \{x\} \times [-ε_x/2,ε_x/2]$ for $ε_x \ge 1/n$. For $K = \bigcup_{j=1}^m K_{x_j}$, we have $\mu(K) \ge m/n$. Hence, if $V ⊃ \mathbb R × \{0\}$ is open, then $\mu(V ) ≥ \sup_{m∈\mathbb N} m/n= ∞$. This implies $\mu(\mathbb R × \{0\}) = ∞$.

How do we get $\{x\} × [−ε_x, ε_x] ⊂ V$? I know the idea is that there exists some $\epsilon_x$ such that the open ball of this radius centered at $x$ is in $V$, but why do open balls in this topology look like this? Also, I didn't really understand what was done after this to show $\mu(\mathbb R × \{0\}) = ∞$, and I'd appreciate if someone could explain in detail.

Thank you!

Comment: @OliverDiaz Why is that? Also, I read your previous comment about (1), it wasn't clear what $K$ to choose.

Comment: Here is a [recent posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4562333/121671) related to this posting of yours. Perhaps you may want to give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better if you solve this problem on your own. The solution you quote as too confusing and inconsistent with notation.

As you already found out:

- a. In the topological space  $X=(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},\tau_d\otimes\tau_e)$, where $\tau_d$ is the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau_e$ is the usual Euclidean topology, a compact set $K$ is of the form $\bigcup^n_{j=1}\{x_j\}\times K_j$, where $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}$, and the $K_1,\ldots,K_n$ are compact sets in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_e)$. It is also clear that $X$ is Hausdorff and locally compact.
- b.  If $f\in\mathcal{C}_c(X)$, then there are points $\{x_j:1\leq j\leq m\}$ and a sequence  of functions $\phi_j\in\mathcal{C}_c((\mathbb{R},\tau_e))$, $1\leq j\leq m$ such that
  $$ f(x_j,y)=\phi_j(y)\qquad 1\leq j\leq m, \quad y\in\mathbb{R}$$
  The map $\Lambda(f):=\sum^m_{j=1}\int_\mathbb{R} \phi_j(y)\,dy$ clearly defines a linear and positive functional on $\mathcal{C}_c(X)$ (why?)
- c.  Form the Riesz representation theorem there is a measure $\mu$ on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}_\Lambda$ that contains $\mathscr{B}(X)$ such that
  $$\Lambda f=\int_X f\,d\mu,\qquad f\in\mathcal{C}_c(X)$$

To determine the marginals of $\mu$ over $(\mathbb{R},\tau_d)$ and $(\mathbb{R},\tau_e)$ first notice that for any fixed $\phi\in\mathcal{C}_c((\mathbb{R},\tau_e))$, and any $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$,
if $f_i(x,y)=\mathbb{1}_{\{x_i\}}(x)\phi(y)$, $i=1,2$, then $f_i\in\mathcal{C}_c(X)$ and
$$\Lambda f_1=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(y)\,dy=\Lambda f_2$$
The Riesz representation theorem applied to $(\mathbb{R},\tau_e)$ and $\tilde{\Lambda}:\phi\mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(y)\,dy$, $\phi\in\mathcal{C}_c((\mathbb{R},\tau_e))$ implies that for any compact set $B\subset\mathbb{R}$, there is a sequence $\phi_n\in \mathcal{C}_c((\mathbb{R},\tau_e))$ such that $\phi_n\searrow\mathbb{1}_B$ point wise, and
$$\int_\mathbb{R}|\mathbb{1}_B(y)-\phi(y)|\,dy\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
Define $g^i_n(x,y)=\mathbb{1}_{\{x_i\}}(x)\phi_n(y)$, $ i = 1,2$. Then each $g^i_n\in\mathcal{C}_c(X)$ $ i = 1,2$, and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Furthermore
$$
\int_X|\mathbb{1}_{\{x_i\}}(x)\mathbb{1}_B(y)-g^i_n(x,y)|\,\mu(dx,dy)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\mathbb{1}_B(y)-\phi_n(y)|\,dy\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
and so,
$$\int_X\mathbb{1}_{\{x_1\}}\mathbb{1}_{B}(y)\,\mu(dx,dy)=\int_X\mathbb{1}_{\{x_2\}}\mathbb{1}_{B}(y)\,\mu(dx,dy)=\lim_n\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_n(y)\,dy=\lambda(B)$$
That is,
$$\begin{align}\mu(\{x\}\times B)=\lambda(B)\tag{1}\label{one}\end{align}$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and any compact set $B$.

(**Solution to 3.**) If $K\subset\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}=E$ is compact, then $K=\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}\times\{0\}$ for some points $x_j\in\mathbb{R}$ and so $\mu(K)=\sum^m_{j=1}\mu(\{x_j\}\times\{0\})=0$ by \eqref{one}.

**(Solution to 4.)** The Riesz representation also implies that for any measurable $A\subset X$
$$ \mu(A)=\inf\{\mu(G):G\,\text{open,}\, A\subset G\}$$
Any open set $G$ that contains $E$, also contains sets of the form $U=\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\{x\}\times(-a_x,a_x)$, $a_x>0$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, there is $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $X_{n_0}=\{x:a_x>\frac{1}{n_0}\}$ is uncountable. Thus, for such $G$
$$\mu(G)\geq\mu^*(U)\geq\sup_{J\subset X_{n_0}}\sum_{x\in J}2a_x=\infty,$$ where the sup is over all finite subsets of $X_{n_0}$. That is $\mu^*(E)=\infty$.

Comment: I'm still reading your answer, and my first question is (1) Why is $f_i \in C_c(X)$? It is the product of a discontinuous function (indicator function on a singleton) with a continuous function $\phi$.

Comment: the function $x\mapsto\mathbb{1}_{\{x_1\}}(x)$ is not discontinuous in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_d)$ since in the discrete topology any set $V\subset\mathbb{R}$ is open.

Comment: Hello! I think I have slightly simpler proof of $\mu(E) = \infty$, building on your ideas. Would you like to check?

Comment: Here it is: http://mathb.in/57282
Thank you! (Theorem 2.7 is as stated in Rudin's RCA)

Comment: Although is is true that Lebesgue's measure is more than sigma-additive (is over-conditnuous) , I don't think that is stated in Rudin's book; you are implicitly using this in your assertion $\lambda(\bigcup_xU_x)\sum_x\lambda(U_x)$. It seems you are mixing relative topologies all over the place when applying Urysohn's lemma. The proof that $\lambda(E)=\infty$ is simpler than that, it is just a matter of showing that  any open set that covers $E$ has a countable collection of open boxes that add up to something very lard.

Comment: Yeah, it is not stated in Rudin's book that the Lebesgue measure obeys $$m\left(\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha\right) = \sum_{\alpha} m(U_\alpha)$$ if the $U_\alpha$ are all disjoint. I think it is okay to use this though. Does the proof look fine otherwise? If not, what part do you think requires some correction? I don't see any issue with Urysohn's lemma.

Comment: Inner regularity is for small sets (sets with finite measure); it may not holds for "large" sets.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution of why $\mu(K) = 0$? I agree that $K = \{x_1,...,x_m\}\times\{0\}$.

Comment: It is fine to use $m(A \cup B) = m(A) + m(B)$ for the Lebesgue measure, where $A,B$ are disjoint - but don't we need to show $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ (and the general countable case)? I'm not sure if your solution covers that.

Comment: Why is a compact set in  $X = (\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},\tau_d\otimes\tau_e)$ of the form $\bigcup^n_{j=1}\{x_j\}\times K_j$. My reasoning is since $\{x_j\}$ is closed, ${pr_1}^{-1} (\{x_j\})$ is closed. $X$ is Hausdorff, hence $K$ is closed,hence $K_j = K \cap {pr_1}^{-1} (\{x_j\})$ is closed, hence compact.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I understand that a compact set in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_d)$ is finite. I want to understand why is a compact set in the product space $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},\tau_d\otimes\tau_e)$ of the form $\bigcup^n_{j=1}\{x_j\}\times K_j$

Comment: @OliverDiaz I understand that a compact set in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_d)$ is finite. I want to understand why is a compact set in the product space $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},\tau_d\otimes\tau_e)$ of the form $\bigcup^n_{j=1}\{x_j\}\times K_j$

Comment: @somitra: project down to $(\mathbb{R},\tau_d)$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes the projection of a compact set $K \subset (\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},\tau_d\otimes\tau_e)$ is finite. Which implies that $K = \bigcup^n_{j=1}\{x_j\}\times A_j$. That $A_j$s are compact as subsets of $(\mathbb{R},\tau_e)$ escapes me.

Comment: @somitra: Each fiber $\{x_j\}\times \mathbb{R}$ is closed. Hence $(\{x_j\}\times \mathbb{R})\cap K$ is compact.  Project down to the Euclidean component ($\mathbb{R},\tau_e$) to conclude that $(\{x_j\}\times \mathbb{R})\cap K=\{x_i\}\times K_j$ for some $K_j$ compact in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_e)$

Comment: @OliverDiaz I get it now